# Download html file using links in php

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

i have a array of links..

```
Array ( [0] => https://edge.sagepub.com/sadfsa/student-resources/chapter-0/learning-objectives 
        [1] => https://edge.sagepub.com/sadfsa/student-resources/chapter-1/learning-objectives )
```

is there a way i can download the html file of this links....

correct me if iam wrong..
Thanks

Comment: Use file_get_contents function for get contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file_get_contents` function can be provided with a URL - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//
// A very simple example that gets a HTTP page.
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.test.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a GET request via php's curl or exec() a curl directly.

You can read more about PHP's curl functionality here https://www.php.net/curl